# Let's help Area51 proposals related to GIS!

Tags: discussion

This SE site is dedicated to GIS, but there are related topics which might not be completely in topic here and deserve their own sites. Let's help them to take off the ground!

Here are some of them:

[CAD/CAM software](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35789/cad-cam-software) - there are some areas where GIS and CAD meets, so could interrests of their users.

[Geography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48899/geography) - another proposal where cross-interrest is obvious.

[Geoscience](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience) - similar to the proposal above.

[Archaeology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44913/archaeology) - one of fields where GIS is applied. It's not very important from GIS perspective, but I know that at least one archaeologist is or at least was here, and I hope that me and him are not the only people interrested in GIS applications in archaeology here.

This post is a community wiki - feel free to add more examples of related Area51 proposals.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's no question - it's just a list CW post (but thanks for asking, it made me do the research on its proper form, which I should have done before - my fault).

Comment: To be appropriate, your post must be a question--please see our [faq](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/faq).  Otherwise it belongs in chat. I think there might be a question here, although I'm unsure what you have in mind: what is the point to creating a list of seemingly related Area51 proposals?

Comment: @whuber Probably as a way to provide "bookmarks" to GIS-related sites is my guess (so that GIS users could go and vote them up so that they can become full-fledged sites). Not really allowed, of course, but some could consider it useful.

Comment: @Michael I'm not so sure about the purpose: my inclination is to vote those proposals *down* and encourage people to come here rather than try to create ultra-specialized sites that will only sow confusion and suck people away from here.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/689/12768) and its answer lead me to impression that this is OK (though some may frown upon it). I found [some similar posts on other sites](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/915), so I think similar CW post should find its place here too.

Comment: Maybe--but you're not even promoting other Area51 sites. I can't figure out what you're trying to do with this thread.  Do you want to promote those sites or discourage their development or something else?

Comment: @whuber: finally I understood your point. I edited the post so that it's clear I want to promote the sites.

Comment: Now that a year has passed, what are your current thoughts? Do you still think we should *help* the related, proposed sites? Or would this Q be more useful as a neutral list of related, proposed sites?

Comment: Either way, maybe it's better or more informative to indicate that a site, such as Geography or CAD, has been deleted (perhaps via strike-through text) or promoted to beta...

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how you feel, but I would like to see all Geodesy and Geomatics questions here instead of on a "sister" site. I don't think they would be off-topic here.

Comment: +1. But given that the Geodesy proposal has all of three followers after four months, it looks like there is little danger of it being created.  Geoscience might get more traction, but in the meantime we're a pretty good home for many geosciences-related questions, too.

Comment: OK. I had different impression, but if Geodesy is on topic here, it shouldn't be proposed, so I edited it away.